# Where is My.ini file? It currently looks to be empty on MySql Server 8.0

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm trying to update some settings for MySQL 8.0 however when I go to the my.ini file all it shows is - [mysqld] and nothing else. I have a windows 2019 server.

I have MySQL workbench installed it points to the my.ini file at the location C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0, so it appears I am looking in the right place.

Within workbench the configuration file doesn't seem to be the one in use for MySql. for example the error logs are pointing to C:drive, however I can see these being generated on another drive E.

At some stage this was set up with the data folder on my E drive - E:\Data\Data - Log files are also in this folder.

I have used the command SET global general_log = 0; to turn on and off the log files, so I can be sure im looking at the correct log file location.

I just cant see where or how to change where the log files etc are pointing to. Any ideas?

Comment: my.ini or my.cnf?

Comment: my.cnf in /etc/mysql includes only 2 directories (etc/mysql/conf.d and etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d). We have copied our stuff after the  switch to mysql 8 in /etc/mysql/mysqld.cnf/mysqld.cnf and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find the my.ini file.

When the default data folder is changed to point to another directory the my.ini will also be located there.

In my case it was in E:\Data\Data\my.ini